# Problem in setting Checked property of radio button

Tags: c#

I have designed a gridview with a radio button inside the itemtemplet. I also have a confirm button.  A user is allowed to check several radio button and when a confirm button is pressed then database is updated with the value of radio button.

But when i check the button it is shown as checked in UI but when I check through code behind, it shows checked property of radio button as false.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < gvTransaction.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      if (!((String.IsNullOrEmpty(gvTransaction.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text)) || (gvTransaction.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text == "&nbsp;")))
      {
          string transactionID = gvTransaction.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
          RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)gvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("rbtSelect"); 
          if (btn.Checked)
          {
              // Although the radiobutton is checked code never reach here. 
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you binding the GridView? If you are doing it in Page Load, make sure that you are not reloading the gridView on page PostBacks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (!IsPostBack) { //Bind GridView here }
```

do let us know if this help

Answer (score 2):

If this is Winforms, my guess would be because the edited Radio button cell value is not committed until it's validated, which happens when the cell lose focus. If you want to commit the modifications immediately, you can handle the [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) event, and call the CommitEdit method in the handler like this:

```
void gvTransaction_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvTransaction.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        gvTransaction.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this if the radiobutton.checkedchanged event.